# Running a cgi perl script as an Administrator

Tags: perl, iis, cgi, impersonation

I'm writing a perl script for a website, and I need to be able to control VirtualBox via the website. I'm not sure where to start, or if I'm even trying to debug in the right area, but here goes.

My server is running IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm also running 2 virtual machines through the vboxmanage command line interface. These VMs are running under SERVER\administrator.

When I open my website, it requests a login. I login to the website as SERVER\administrator and click a link that calls my script using an xmlhttprequest. Now, normally, it doesn't matter what user I run these as, but with vboxmanage, if I run the command as a different user, the list of VMs is different. I tried `whoami`, which returned `SERVER\administrator`, but `%DOMAINNAME%\%USERNAME%` returns the domain that the server is connected to as dommainname and `SERVER$` as the username. The vboxmanage command then fails.

On the website, impersonation is turned on. When I turn impersonation off, the `whoami` request changes to be `iis apppool\website`. Any ideas on how to get around this?

As a final note, I've thought about using runas, but since it prompts for a password, there's no way to call it through scripting (and that would be a poor security decision, I'd imagine).

Answer (score 0):

This is an oft recurring, well-known and well-solved problem. Instead of having one big program dealing with requests from the Web and managing the VM (strong coupling), separate the concern and write two programs, each doing exactly one task.

The user facing program running in the Web server context can continue with limited privileges. The VM manager is a stand-alone program running with the necessary admin privileges, either repeatedly from the scheduler or as daemon/service.

Have the first communicate with the second over a [message-queue](/questions/tagged/message-queue).